# How to get returned class properties when passing as argument in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I having issue with getting properies of class when I'm passing that as parameter in another class method

My issue is so complicted in my code and I tried to simplified it to get the solution

imagine I have class as User like this :

```
class User {
  name!:string 

  static setName(_name:string){
    const user = new User()
    user.name = _name 
    return user
 
  }

}
```

and Company with almost same properties:

```
class Company {
  name!:string 
  brand!:string = 'mtx'

  static setName(_name:string){
    const company = new Company()
    company.name = _name 
    return company
  }

}
```

and I have Registration Class that has register method:

```
class Registration {

  static register<K >(name:string,Model: K & { setName:(n:string)=>K}): K{
   return Model.setName(name)
  }

}
```

and I register user and company in this way :

```
let user = Registration.register('mamad',User)
let company = Registration.register('mamad',Company)
```

so this is working for user but for company returns this error :

[image]

and here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAjGBsEMGdoAgKrQKYCc4G9hzgO0gLbICEAXNAC6oCWuA5nCDpZBdaHChQHKHIAUAfXxFyVWnQCUWHDlAB7XJTgBXFOgC8eZAHdE6-pOyy1aAHQjkcLcL6NZcVMgorUuVeuzGAviF-AIGHgAYXkCAAdIXABPTGNLMkoaens4ACNUKIATRPEUrQByAgoADwKmTgpWdk5nXiIhSzFkqRlZBSUKOAUIqNitXF04UN6Yw2M5MMiYizsbS1ScJxc3bqm+nz8wKFg4ACVkOmok6sU44xY2DicjyjQAHgBpOAA+fiakiQAaAFl5LOQ4FIcGeADJMLUeHxSO9mhJJBoXo9vJJgY82o5nK53H8AeAzFx6gJLEYcP5-MBwM4PGhrPtDscqKdcGYboy0PwioRIFkCl8kGgjFSuj1pv16bcmWxFKyGXdUJyCNzeV8RmKjAF1jEgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `K &` so it will look like this:

```
class Registration {

  static register<K >(name:string,Model: { setName:(n:string)=>K}): K{
   return Model.setName(name)
  }

}
```

When you are calling:

```
let company = Registration.register('mamad',Company)
```

You are not supplying `K` argument, you are only basically supplying the `setName`, because that is present as static property. If you would have the `K &` part, then you would need to be supplying actual instance, `new Company()` or such in order to be able to refer to instance fields.

Comment: aha thanks it works :), I didn't pay attention to that